# Boolean equation Indexing exercise

Tags: logic

*By the  method of indexing, prove the following Boolean equation to be valid:*

*(A ∪ B)′ ∩ C = (C ∩ A′) ∪ (C ∩ B′)*

What I tried to do - but somehow it doesn't go right, where did I made a mistake, Please?

A - 1,2,3,4

B - 1,2,5,6

C - 1,3,5,7

1)  A ∪ B = (1,2,3,4,5,6) so (A ∪ B)′ =(7,8)

(7,8)  ∩ (1,3,5,7) = (7)

2)  (C ∩ A′) = (1,3,5,7) ∩ (5,6,7,8) = (5,7)

(C ∩ B′) = (1,3,5,7) ∩ (3,4,7,8) = (3,7)

so (5,7) ∪ (3,7) = (3,5,7)

3) So it comes to (7) = (3,5,7) what surely can't be right?

Comment: I believe the initial expression is incorrect. Are you sure it's not (A ∪ B)′ ∩ C = (C ∩ A′) ∩ (C ∩ B′)? (Notice that I put intersection instead of union between the parenthesis.)

Comment: This is as it is in the book,   ∪  (page 15, Smullyan, A Beginners Guide to Mathematical Logic) - but I thought the same thing that perhaps it is typo?

Comment: I think it must be a typo, because your proof looks correct. I also drew the diagram which indicated the same thing.

Comment: @Pé de Leão , Thank You, I was just afraid that perhaps I am doing something wrong :)

Comment: Just to reinforce that Pe de Leao's is correct, the only thing that is changed by the negation of (A u B), is what's inside the parenthesis [A u B] NOT what is between the parenthesis and C [(  ) n C].  So, the correct statement would be, (A u B)' n C = (A' n C) n (B' n C).

Comment: Indeed.   (A ∪ B)′ ∩ C = (A′ ∩ B′) ∩ (C ∩ C) = (C ∩ A′) ∩ (C ∩ B′)

Comment: Conversely,  (C ∩ A′) ∪ (C ∩ B′) = (A′ ∪ B′) ∩ C = (A ∩ B)′ ∩ C

Answer (score 2):

As the comments note there is an error in the problem. To check the problem, one can use truth tables. Here is a [truth table](https://mrieppel.net/prog/truthtable.html) for the original claim:

> (A ∪ B)′ ∩ C = (C ∩ A′) ∪ (C ∩ B′)

[image]

Here is a truth table for the modified claim:

> (A ∪ B)′ ∩ C = (C ∩ A′) ∩ (C ∩ B′)

[image]

---

Michael Rieppel. Truth Table Generator. Generated on May 12, 2019 at https://mrieppel.net/prog/truthtable.html